What is the inverse of function $(1+\cos x)/(1+\sin x)=y$ when $0<x<\pi/4$
What is the inverse of this function,
$$\frac{1+\cos x}{1+\sin x}=y$$
such that $0<x<\frac{\pi}{4}?$
I just want to go from $f(x)=y$ to   $x= f^{ −1}(y).$
So a way to separate the $x$.

Please use latex

Is there a reason to expect a good closed form for the inverse?

Have you had any thoughts on this yourself?

The substitution $t=\tan(\frac{1}{2}x)$ will help.

@MarkBennet yes I was able to solve it after posting the question but in a different way and it seems these amazing people have left a beautiful answer to this question, I'll check to see which one answers in the most easy way when I get free and then Close the question.

Note that writing $1+\sin x$ and $1+\cos x$ in terms of $\sin \frac x2$ and $\cos \frac x2$ will give you some identities you might want to remember.

Hint:
First note that
$$\frac{1+\cos(y)}{1+\sin(y)}=x$$
implies that
$$\frac{1+\sin(y)}{1+\cos(y)}=\frac1x$$
or
$$\frac12\sec^2(\frac y2)+\tan(\frac y2)=\frac1x$$
Thus, use $\sec^2(\frac y2)=1+\tan^2(\frac y2)$ and quadratic formula.
